What was the Cafe Afghan?
In chapter 22 and 23 of Penguin Lost, Viktor and Andrey Pavlovich made a big show of delivering some artificial limbs to the Cafe Afghan to promote the latter's campaign.
What, exactly, was the Cafe Afghan? Is that a place where veterans of the Soviet war in Afghanistan frequented? I do vaguely remember from Zinky Boys that injured veterans weren't always given the best artificial limbs, and the book's set less than 10 years after that war ended. Is that what the book is referring to, or am I misreading it?
Also, is this based on a real place?

The spectator describes is as "Cafe Afghan, haunt of disabled war veterans."
